# Flow type checking a action$ observable

Tags: observable, flowtype, redux-observable, flow-typed

Is it possible to flow type check an observable? I am using redux-observable to build out epics that watch for actions to dispatch and, if there is a match, they run some async code. The `action$` argument to the epic is an observable, but there seems to be no `Observable<>` type in Flow. How does one properly assign a flow type to `action$`?

```
// @ flow
const fetchApiEpic = (action$) => {
  ...
};
```

Contents of `action$`:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly possible to flow type RxJS and redux-observable, but neither library currently provides official type definitions for them so you'd need to find community ones (if they exist) or create your own.

The [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) projects contains unofficial type definitions for RxJS v5, but not any for redux-observable. You could use the [TypeScript definition](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/master/index.d.ts) for it as a reference, if you wanted to create your own.